# How can I add an Image from PIL to a MoviePY video?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, moviepy

How can I add an Image from PIL to a MoviePY video?

I tried searching on the internet but couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 1):

See https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.fromarray : "Pillow images can also be converted to arrays".

For example:

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
from moviepy.editor import *

im = Image.open("test.jpg")
image_array = np.array(im)
clip = ImageClip(image_array).set_duration(5)
clip.write_videofile("test.mp4", fps=24)
```